# if referencing something contained in an Appendix, would I say appendix's?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, possessives

So my paper is about a particular book and i'm referencing one of the appendices for my argument. The title of the appendix is Nagel's brain, and i'm trying to say the quote is from the appendix's/appendices' namesake, and i'm not sure which would be appropriate.

Comment: The pronoun "I" should be capitalized, even in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Usually major words are capitalized in titles.  Prepositions and articles are usually not capitalized in titles.  Did you mean to capitalize the "b" in "brain"?

Comment: Apologies @Jasper. I was totally focused on word choice and totally slopped it up grammar-wise. I did in fact mean to say Nagel's Brain. 

I was thinking this would work but it kind of sounds weird:
 
"In Nagel’s Brain, we are provided a quote from the appendix’s namesake:..." 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

"Appendix" is the singular form.  You are referring to one appendix's title.

Some style guides recommend consistently omitting the "s" after "x'" or "s'" when forming a possessive; some style guides recommend consistently including the "s" after "x'" but not after "s'"; and other style guides recommend consistently including the "s" after "x'" or "s'" in the same situation.

Comment: I agree - either *appendix’s* or *appendix’* works. *appendices* is plural so that word is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid the awkwardness of "appendix's", which is grammatical and correct but awkward and rarely seen, you can instead indicate the genitive with ***of***.

> the namesake **of the** appendix

Answer (score 1):

Technically the possessive would be either "appendix's" or "appendix'" ... but, like many other words, this construction is awkward and best avoided.

> The **appendix of** Noah's Brain contains a chart which shows ...

If there is more than one appendix, you can refer to them by name / number:

> In Noah's Brain, **Appendix 1**, there is a chart which shows ...